# How can I create my custom Gaming device?

Tags: bluetooth, drivers, oculus, leap-motion, wiimote

I am developing a custom gaming device like Leap Motion. But I am wondering how to plan structure of SDK's and drivers.
Basically, my device (MCU with bluetooth) will transfer data through Bluetooth to the Host device (Linux, MAC, PC, Android and iOS) and then that the data will be processed through opencv program. Then the processed data can be used by Unity Games.

I particularly don't want to embed OpenCV code in Unity code.

How does devices like Leap Motion, Oculus Rift, Wii Remote handle this ?

Comment: Look at the HID profile.  No extra drivers needed... just some handling of your messaging.

Comment: @Brad thanks. Once I get data from HID and process it in open case, how can I interface this data to unity or unreal ?